# What is the schedule on this Cron?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cron job with the following expression:

```
*/30 */2 * * *
```

Would this run every half hour AND every 2 hours or will it run every 2.5 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every even hour, it will run at :00 and :30 - every day of the week.

E.g., 0:00, 0:30, 2:00, 2:30...12:00, 12:30, 14:00, 14:30...22:00, 22:30

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

From `crontab(5)`:

```
Commands are executed by cron(8) when the minute, hour, and month of year fields match
the current time, and when at least one of the two day fields (day of month, or day of
week) match the current time
```

So your entry will run when the minute is 0 or 30 and the hour is even - at 0:00, 0:30, 2:00, 2:30, ....

Answer (score 0):

One hour - no runs

Next hour - runs every 30 minutes